# Tips for quickly formatting a single line of XML?

Tags: vimscript, formatting, filetype-xml

I have a log file with lots of web service XML data (example follows). Ideally I would like to just go to a line and type `,x` to create pretty formatted XML for readability.

```
 Response XML: <ZZZZZ_EXBListLocalEftposRS xmlns="http://types.wise.zzzzz.com/2005/06"><PayLoad><TimeStamp>2015-04-07T10:25:18.797+12:00</TimeStamp></PayLoad><Success/><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="true" ProbablyLocal="true">TEST_EFTD</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="true" ProbablyLocal="true">TEST_EFT</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadD1</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadD2</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadD3</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadNoP</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS2</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS3</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS4</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS5</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadS6</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="true">TESTBadScl</EftposTerminalID><EftposTerminalID CurrentlyMapped="false" ProbablyLocal="false">TESTBadTyp</EftposTerminalID></ZZZZZ_EXBListLocalEftposRS>
```

Currently, I can format the line as follows

1. put the XML stuff on a new line (If you don't do this xmllint has problems)
2. get the line number I need (199 in this case)
3. call [xmllint.exe](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Format_your_xml_document_using_xmllint) as follows:

   `:199 :!C:\apps\xmllint.exe % --format`

Is there some way to automate some or all of this process?

I'm using gvim on windows, and xmllint.exe from google code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have most of the pieces:

```
:199 :!C:\apps\xmllint.exe % --format
```

You can use `:.` for the current line:

```
:.!C:\apps\xmllint.exe % --format
```

To get rid of the preamble before the XML, you can use `0dt<`. Inside a command-line, that's done with `:normal!`:

```
:execute 'normal! 0dt<' | .!C:\apps\xmllint.exe % --format
```

Now, all that is left is creating a mapping (note how some keys need a special format):

```
nnoremap ,x :execute 'normal! 0dt<lt>' <Bar> .!C:\apps\xmllint.exe % --format<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic). It has support for xml lint testing using xmllint. This will do the checking and report errors and not directly fix the problem with the XML however.